# onchange on radiobutton not working correctly in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, radio-button

I'm forced to work with IE8 (8.0.7601.17514) and I have this simple page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action=".">
    <input type="radio" name="rad" value="1" onchange="alert(1);"/>
    <input type="radio" name="rad" value="0" onchange="alert(0);" checked="checked"/>
</form>
<a href="http://google.com">some dummy link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

What I expect is that as the second radio button is selected, clicking on the first one will immediately raise an Alert. This works fine in FF.

What actually happens is that when I click the first radio, nothing happens. Then, when the element is blurred (eg. I click somewhere else, the other radio, some link in the page etc), THEN the alert is raised.

Is there a workaround to this?

**EDIT:**

apparently this behavior is exactly according to [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents)

> **change**
>
> The change event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus. This event is valid for INPUT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA. element.

(thanks to @mu-is-too-short).

The workaround to this is to add a onclick blur+focus:

```
function radioClick()
{
 this.blur();  
 this.focus();  
}


<input type="radio" name="rad" value="1" onclick="radioClick" onchange="alert(1);"/>
```

Comment: working fine for me in IE8 - http://jsfiddle.net/uMD9h/

Comment: @Pranav nope, tried the link u sent in ie8 and it won't work

Comment: strange...it is working absolutely fine for me in IE8 with window XP.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Internet Explorer (up to at least IE8) clicking a radio button or checkbox to change its value does not actually trigger the onChange event until the the input loses focus.

Thus you need to somehow trigger the blur event yourself.. one suggestiong would be to have a function: as follows:

```
function radioClick()
{
 this.blur();  
 this.focus();  
}


<input type="radio" name="rad" value="1" onclick="radioClick" onchange="alert(1);"/>
```

Now your `onchange` event should be triggered but as you can see it is redundant code thus you are better off just using the `onclick` event handler.

The better solution is to use a modern javascript library like jquery which handles all these quirks for you..

Comment: i think onchange is designed for that ..until the control does not lose focus it means modification is still going on ...

Answer (score 8):

Technically, IE actually got this right. From the [fine specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents):

> **change**
>
> The change event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus. This event is valid for INPUT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA. element.

So in order for a change event to be trigger, the specification says that the element must lose focus (i.e. a blur is required). The usual kludge is to use a click handler or force the blur as the others have suggested.

Answer (score 2):

use onclick, but ie is call the event handler before the value (or checked attribute) was changed
[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: why onclick ?? onchange is appropriate for this .

Comment: because change only fire when element lost focus in ie