# datetimepicker and Backbone.View Interaction

Tags: jquery-ui, backbone.js

This is the code:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {std:"",
               pod:""
              }
});

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:'ul',
    events: {
    'change input' : 'changed',  // When input changes, call changed.
    'hover .std'   : 'timepick', // 
    'mouseout .std': 'doesntwork'
    },
    template:_.template($('#mytemplate').html()),

    initialize: function() {
        this.model.bind('change:pod',this.render,this); // When pod changes, re-render
    },
    timepick: function(e) {
        $('.std').each(function(){
            $.datepicker.setDefaults({dateFormat:'mm-dd'});
            $(this).datetimepicker({timeFormat:'hh:mm',ampm:false});
        });
    },
    doesntwork: function() {
        // Would this.model.set here but mouseout happens when you select date/time values with mouse
    },
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    changed: function(e) {
        var value = $(e.currentTarget).val();       // Get Change value
        var cls = $(e.currentTarget).attr('class'); //Get Class of changed input
        var obj = {}; 
        obj[cls] = value;                       // The model variables match class names
        this.model.set(obj);                        // this.model.set({'std':value})
    }
});
```

I have a datetimepicker in the UI I'm working on, and having difficulties assigning the value that is selected from the datetimepicker to MyModel.

It appears from using console.log output that 'change input' is triggered when clicking on the DTP and assigns the default value of (MM-DD 00:00). Even when you select a different date/time value than the default, the 'change input' is not triggered again, unless you click on the input box (for a second time), and then the correct value is assigned. Not very user-friendly.

So I had the idea that I would just assign the value on mouseout, which didn't work since mouseout happens when you start to select date/time values. I also tried blur, and that didn't work either.

Where am I going wrong?

Edit: Here is a jsfiddle.net link that illustrates my problem http://jsfiddle.net/9gSUe/1/

Comment: A change event is not triggered until the `<input>` loses focus, [the HTML spec even says so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10579168/479863). Does that sound like what's happening? If so then there should be an appropriate event from the datetimepicker that you could use.

Comment: From what I observed, the datetimepicker loses focus before the desired date/time value is selected. I will look into the events for the datetimepicker. Thanks for link as well.

Comment: But it needs to lose focus *after* the value is changed. Can you set up a demo at jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com to make it easier to see what's happening?

Comment: @mu is too short, edited question with jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're getting tripped up by jQuery UI's CSS. When you bind a datepicker to an `<input>`, jQuery UI will add a `hasDatepicker` class to the `<input>`. Then you do this:

```
var cls = $(e.currentTarget).attr('class');
```

on the `<input>` and get `'std hasDatepicker'` in `cls`.

There are too many things that will mess around with `class` so you're better off using something else to identify the property you want to change. You could use an `id` if there is only one `std`:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input id="std" class="std" ...>

// JavaScript
var cls = e.currentTarget.id;
```

or the `name` attribute:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input name="std" class="std" ...>

// JavaScript
var cls = $(e.currentTarget).attr('name');
```

or perhaps even a HTML5 data attribute:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input class="std" data-attr="std" ...>

// JavaScript
var cls = $(e.currentTarget).data('attr');
```

I think the `name` attribute would be the most natural: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/RRKVJ/

And a couple side issues:

- Your fiddle was including multiple versions of jQuery and that's generally a bad idea.
- You don't have to build an object for [`set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set), you can say just `m.set(attr, value)` if you're just setting one attribute.
- You don't have to `$(this.el)` in your views, newer Backbones have [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) already cached.
- `console.log` can handle multiple arguments so you can say `console.log('Std: ', attrs.std, ' Pod: ', attrs.pod, ' Poa: ', attrs.poa);` instead of `console.log('Std: ' + attrs.std + ' Pod: ' + attrs.pod + ' Poa: ' + attrs.poa);` if you don't want `+` stringify things behind your back.