# Jquery toggle only working after clicking on table row IE8

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8

I have a small amount of Jquery that hides/shows two elements based on the clicking of a check box. Now this works perfectly in Firefox but when i test in IE8 the toggle will only work after I click the the textbox then click anywhere within the TR. Here is my checkbox code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="noEOS@(Model.QuoteLineKey)" name="noEOS@(Model.QuoteLineKey)" checked="@(Model.HasNoEndOfSupportDate)" onchange='javascript: noEOS(@(Model.QuoteLineKey)); return false;'/>
```

And here is my Jquery function

```
function noEOS(id) {

        $('#spanNoEOS' + id).toggle();
        $('#spanEOS' + id).toggle();
        if ($('#noEOS' + id).is(':checked')) {
            $('#EndOfSupportDate' + id).val('');
        } else {
            $('#EndOfSupportDate' + id).val($('#CoTermExpiryDate').val());
        }
    }
```

I have tried changing the .toggle to the below with no success.

```
    var elem = $('#spanNoEOS' + id)[0];
    if (elem.style.display == 'none')
        $('#spanNoEOS' + id).show();
    else {
        $('#spanNoEOS' + id).hide();
    }
    var elem2 = $('#spanNoEOS' + id)[0];
    if (elem2.style.display == 'none')
        $('#spanEOS' + id).show();
    else {
        $('#spanEOS' + id).hide();
    }
```

Comment: Post the full code to reproduce your question or create a jsfiddle - IE and FF have many particular threatment for DOM and var closures

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579019/onchange-on-radiobutton-not-working-correctly-in-ie8

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   var e = $('#spanEOS' + id);
   e.is(':hidden') ? e.show() : e.hide();

   var e2 = $('#spanNoEOS' + id);
   e2.is(':hidden') ? e2.show : e2.hide();
```

Comment: Same thing happening in IE8, the tr needs to clicked for the hide/show to work.